# STATICFILES DJANGO

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have a problem with Django, managing static files.. I know there are already similar questions here and I have gone through them all and tried them, but an error still pops up.
here is my code

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
BASE_DIR / "static", 
 ]
```

and the following message pops up

> BASE_DIR/'static',
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: This is syntax error.
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR + "/static",  ]`

Answer (score 1):

Django is supporting pathlib starting from verson 3.1.

Make sure you are using supported Django version and your settings file has:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
```